# Преобразование всех словарей из списка Python

Tags: python

У меня есть список словарей с датами. Я написал код функции, которая должна преобразовать дату в нужный мне формат. Если словарь один, то функция работает так как надо:

```
import datetime
days = {'date': '2010-08-07T19:36:14.672617'}


def all_date(days):
    days['date'] = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(days['date'])
    day_x = datetime.datetime.strftime(days['date'], '%d.%m.%Y')
    return day_x

print(all_date(days))
```

Результат:

```
07.08.2010
```

Если я подставляю список словарей, то возникает ошибка:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Я переписал код, но в результате только первая дата:

```
import datetime
days = [{'date': '2010-08-07T19:36:14.672617'}, {'date': '2015-08-07T19:36:14.672617'}, {'date': '2020-08-07T19:36:14.672617'}]

def all_date(days):
    for i in range(len(days)): 
        days[i]['date'] = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(days[i]['date'])
        day_x = datetime.datetime.strftime(days[i]['date'], '%d.%m.%Y')
        return day_x

print(all_date(days)
```

Сейчас я получаю:

```
07.08.2010
```

А надо получить:

```
07.08.2010
07.08.2015
07.08.2020
```

Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: Проще оставить вашу первую функцию, просто использовать ее для каждого словаря в списке: `print(*[all_date(dict_) for dict_ in days])`. А вообще проблема у вас в том, что в первой же итерации вы возвращаете значение. Вам нужно или внутри функции поставить список, в который последовательно добавлять результаты, после чего весь его вернуть, или можно использовать `yield` вместе `return`, но тогда вывод будет какой-то такой: `for date in all_date(days): print(date)`

Comment: А, еще заметил: у вас неправильно записан список словарей. Вы ввели его так, что у вас в списке один словарь, в котором много раз используется ключ 'date'. Так как в словаре хранятся уникальные ключи, то в итоге у вас и словарь состоит из одной даты.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что ты возвращаешь `return day_x`, то есть, первую преобразованную дату. Тебе следует создать список, в него в цикле складывать свои day_x, а потом уже его вернуть.
Как-то так:

```
def all_date(days):
    # это список, где будут сохраняться даты
    result = []
    for i in range(len(days)): 
        days[i]['date'] = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(days[i]['date'])
        day_x = datetime.datetime.strftime(days[i]['date'], '%d.%m.%Y')
        # вместо return добавляем его в список
        result.add(day_x)
  # возвращаем в итоге список всех дат
  return result
```

При этом, цикл можно оптимизировать. Цикл for умеет перебирать коллекции, без обращения к индексу. `for o in days`

Функция будет выглядеть так:

```
def all_date(days):
    # это список, где будут сохраняться даты
    result = []
    for o in days: 
        o['date'] = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(o['date'])
        day_x = datetime.datetime.strftime(o['date'], '%d.%m.%Y')
        # вместо return добавляем его в список
        result.add(day_x)
  # возвращаем в итоге список всех дат
  return result
```

Answer (score 2):

Все можно сделать в одну строку, поскольку метод `strftime()` применим к объекту `datetime`, создаваемый через `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat()`. В результате все делается за один проход.

В итоге в цикле подаваемый список словарей обрабатываем строкой с двойным преобразованием `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(d['date']).strftime('%d.%m.%Y')`

```
import datetime

def all_date(days):
    return [datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(d['date']).strftime('%d.%m.%Y') for d in days]

days = [{'date': '2010-08-07T19:36:14.672617'}, {'date': '2015-08-07T19:36:14.672617'}, {'date': '2020-08-07T19:36:14.672617'}]

print(*all_date(days), sep='\n')
```

Вывод:

```
07.08.2010
07.08.2015
07.08.2020
```